# Mouse Over issue_Error Message_Can't convert from void to WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Mouse Over issue_Error Message_Can't convert from void to WebElement.

Showing the "Can't convert from void to WebElement" at WebElement creation line.
Attached screenshot.

My Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import[enter image description here][1] org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class webelements2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\rpremala003\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.carmax.com/");
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement menuElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("CARS FOR SALE")).click();
        builder.moveToElement(menuElement).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Buying from CarMax")).click();      
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.click()` doesn't return an element and you are trying to assign the `.click()` result into a `WebElement`. Just remove the `.click()` and it should work without error.

```
WebElement menuElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("CARS FOR SALE")).click();
```

should be

```
WebElement menuElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("CARS FOR SALE"));
```